# JPA mapping to Map<Object, Interger>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've 3 tables:
- lots: has column gen_id
- onhand_quantities: has column gen_id,sub_inventory_code, quantity
- subinventory: has column sub_inventory_code

I map to 2 objects: Lots, SubInventory and I would like to mapping in object Lots with property is: `Map<SubInventory, Integer> getOnhandQuantity()`

Integer type in this Map is value of quantity column.
Please help me.

Comment: I believe in `lots` there should be something like `lot_id` and in `onhand_quantities` there should also be that `lot_id` in it right? If not, the overall design just doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @duykaka my below answer works hope you were able to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Just a brief search in Hibernate document give me information on using an associated entity as key of a Map (aka [Ternary Association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-ternary))

Quoted from the manual:

> There are three possible approaches to mapping a ternary association.
>   One approach is to use a Map with an association as its index:
>
> Example 7.31. Ternary association mapping
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class Company {
>    @Id 
>    int id;
>    ...
>    @OneToMany // unidirectional
>    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="employee_id")
>    Map<Employee, Contract> contracts;
> }
>
> // or
>
> <map name="contracts">
>     <key column="employer_id" not-null="true"/>
>     <map-key-many-to-many column="employee_id" class="Employee"/>
>     <one-to-many class="Contract"/>
> </map>
> ```
>
> A second approach is to remodel the association as an entity class.
>   This is the most common approach. A final alternative is to use
>   composite elements, which will be discussed later.

To map it back to your original example: Company -> Lots, Employee -> SubInventory, Contract -> OnhandQuantity

Personally I would rather make them as a simple relationship, and construct Map etc on the fly whenever it is needed.

---

Haven't tried, but a further look get me to an example in `@MapKeyColumn`, which in combination with the above sample, should give something reasonable like:

```
class Lot {
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="sub_inventory_id")
    @CollectionTable(name="onhand_quantities")
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Map<SubInventory, Integer> onhandQuantities;

}
```

Comment: '@CollectionTable(name="onhand_quantities")' we need add joinColumn is gen_id. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The below code in the Lots entity should do.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "ONHAND_QUANTITIES", joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="GEN_ID"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="SUBINVENTORY_CODE")
@Column(name="QUANTITY")
private Map<SubInventory, Integer> onHandQuantity;
```

I am trying to test this.

I got this solution from the below link.

[Reference key issue while doing many to many relationship using @ElementCollection, @MapKeyJoinColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547025/reference-key-issue-while-doing-many-to-many-relationship-using-elementcollecti)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOTS")
public class Lots implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "GEN_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "ONHAND_QUANTITIES", joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="GEN_ID"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="SUBINVENTORY_CODE")
    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private Map<SubInventory, Integer> onHandQuantity;

   ......// getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBINVENTORY")
public class SubInventory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="SUBINVENTORY_CODE")
    private Long id;

    ......// getters and setters
}
```